# Aggregate SQL formula

Tags: sql-server

I want to get SUM divided by COUNT in a column

```
Select date,SUM(OOC) OOC,SUM(SUM_CVOICE) SUM, Count(SUM_CVOICE) Cnt,SUM(SUM_CVOICE)/Count(SUM_CVOICE) CVOICE
from #Temp
group by date
order by date

date    OOC SUM Cnt CVOICE
03/01/2017  1569    19445   11252   1
04/01/2017  235 8299    4842    1
05/01/2017  154 11851   6361    1
```

It doesn't gives exact decimal values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`disvision` is tricky in SQL Server, you need to do implicit conversion, otherwise `/` will take the integer part of the result.

```
Select date,
       SUM(OOC) as OOC,
       SUM(SUM_CVOICE) as SUM, 
       Count(SUM_CVOICE) as Cnt,
       SUM(SUM_CVOICE)*1.0/Count(SUM_CVOICE) as CVOICE
from #Temp
group by date
order by date
```

Comment: Anytime, Mate :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does integer arithmetic.  So, the simple answer is to convert your value to a non-integer in some way.  A simple way is to multiply by `* 1.0`:

```
Select date, SUM(OOC) as OOC, SUM(SUM_CVOICE) as SUM,
       Count(SUM_CVOICE) as cnt,
       SUM(SUM_CVOICE)*1.0 / Count(SUM_CVOICE) as CVOICE
from #Temp
group by date
order by date;
```

However, what you are calculating is called the average.  So, this is simpler:

```
Select date, sum(OOC) as OOC, sum(SUM_CVOICE) as SUM,
       Count(SUM_CVOICE) as cnt,
       avg(SUM_CVOICE * 1.0) as CVOICE
from #Temp
group by date
order by date;
```

Note that SQL Server also uses integer arithmetic for the average, so you need to convert to a non-integer as well.